# How the "And" filter query works in Firebase/Flutter when multiple where filters are connected or is there any other solution?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this following Firebase query in Flutter where I would like to get no result when both or either of the user doesn't exist in document:

```
  _firestore
    .collection('chat')
    .where("users.user1", isNotEqualTo: null)
    .where("users.user3", isNotEqualTo: null)
    .get()
```

But I still get 1 result when user1 exist but not user3. It seems like connecting where clause in firebase works as OR but not AND. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: I would not expect this query to always fail entirely, because you can't have two not-equals filters on different fields in a single query.  See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations).  "In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons **must all filter on the same field**."

Comment: Thanks Doug.. Tried with isEqualTo and that works.

Comment: It would have helped to know what was actually in the documents you're trying to query.  You didn't specify that you were looking for a combination of boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
_firestore
  .collection('chat')
  .where("users.user1", isEqualTo: true)
  .where("users.user3", isEqualTo: true)
  .get()
```